# A conjecture about generating algebras on a probability space

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose that $(X,\mathscr F,\mathbb P)$ is a probability space. Let $\mathscr E\subseteq\mathscr F$ be an algebra (*i.e.*, it is a non-empty collection closed under complementation and finite unions) that generates the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr F$: $\sigma(\mathscr E)=\mathscr F$.

Let $F\in\mathscr F$. Is it true that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists some $E\in\mathscr E$ such that $$|\mathbb P(E)-\mathbb P(F)|<\varepsilon?$$ One might try considering the outer measure generated by $\mathbb P|\mathscr E$, but an exact proof or counterexample has eluded me.

Thank you for any input in advance.

---

ADDED: I had tried using [Dynkin’s lemma](https://planetmath.org/dynkinslemma) first, but I was unable to prove that the subcollection of such sets in $\mathscr F$ that satisfy the desired property was a [Dynkin system](https://planetmath.org/dynkinsystem) (in particular, I couldn’t directly show that the subcollection was closed under taking nested differences). However, the answer by user24142 helped me realize that another generating-class argument, based on the [monotone-class lemma](https://planetmath.org/monotoneclasstheorem), easily implies the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conjecture is correct. The reason is that the set of sets that you can approximate within $\mathscr{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. That its closed under complements should be clear, and the countable union condition isn't too hard. It therefore is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains $\mathscr E$ and is contained by $\mathscr F$, so it must be $\mathscr F$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wrote up the details for my records below—note that I use the monotone-class lemma, which makes it possible to circumvent the somewhat tedious details of checking whether the collection is closed under countable unions.

Answer (score 0):

This is an elaboration of the (slightly simplified version of the) answer suggested by user24142.

Let $$\mathscr S\equiv\{F\in\mathscr F\,|\,\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists E\in\mathscr E:|\mathbb P(E)-\mathbb P(F)|<\varepsilon\}.$$ Clearly, $\mathscr E\subseteq\mathscr S$. I claim that $\mathscr S$ is a monotone class. Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and suppose that $(F_m)_{m\in\mathbb N}$ is a non-decreasing collection of sets in $\mathscr S$; let $F$ denote their union. Then, since $\lim_{m\to\infty}\mathbb P(F_m)=\mathbb P(F)$, there exists some $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $|\mathbb P(F_n)-\mathbb P(F)|<\varepsilon/2$. For such an $F_n$, choose $E\in\mathscr E$ such that $|\mathbb P(E)-\mathbb P(F_n)|<\varepsilon/2$. Then, $|\mathbb P(E)-\mathbb P(F)|<\varepsilon$. It follows that $F\in\mathscr S$. A similar argument shows that $\mathscr S$ is closed under countable non-increasing intersections. It follows that $\mathscr S$ is a monotone class, indeed, so the monotone-class lemma (remember that $\mathscr E$ is an algebra) implies that $\mathscr F=\sigma(\mathscr E) \subseteq \mathscr S$, as desired.

Comment: @NateEldredge Since $F_1\subseteq F_2\subseteq\ldots\subseteq F\equiv\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_n$ by assumption, one has that $\mathbb P(F_n)\to \mathbb P(F)$ as $n\to\infty$. I just need ONE SINGLE $F_n\in\mathscr S$ ($n$ large enough) with the property that $|\mathbb P(F_n)-\mathbb P(F)|<\varepsilon/2$. For that particular $F_n$, choose $E\in\mathscr E$ such that $|\mathbb P(E)-\mathbb P(F_n)|<\varepsilon/2$. Combining these two inequalities, one has $|\mathbb P(E)-\mathbb P(F)|<\varepsilon$. That is all I need to conclude that $F\in\mathscr S$, given that $\varepsilon>0$ has been arbitrary.

Comment: Oh, I see now.  I was confused because $n$ was used in two different ways.  I would denote your "one single set" as $F_N$ or something like that.

Comment: @NateEldredge Fair enough. I changed the “generic $n$” to $m$.